# Yarn - error Couldn't find any versions for "@typescript-eslint/type-utils" that matches "5.31.0"

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm

working on node app, with docker.

getting the error during image build, in the install step.

locally the installation works fine.

we use nexus, but again locally through nexus the installation works.

I tried adding resolutions for the packages in the error still, yarn throws the title error.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-graphql-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/my-graphql-service.git",
  "author": "Itay Tur",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:edge2": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon -r dotenv/config src/index.ts dotenv_config_path=config/edge2.env",
    "dev:qa": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon -r dotenv/config src/index.ts dotenv_config_path=config/qa.env",
    "generate:integrations": "node src/generate-integrations-code.js",
    "build": "rimraf build && NODE_ENV=production tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node -r dotenv/config build/index.js dotenv_config_path=.env.graph",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development jest --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=development jest --watch --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "pretty-format": "^26.0.1",
    "jest-diff": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-matcher-utils": "^25.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/type-utils": "@5.30.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/utils": "5.30.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@graphile-contrib/pg-order-by-related": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector": "^6.1.0",
    "@graphile/pg-aggregates": "^0.1.0",
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "2.1.22",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cptls-common-nodejs": "^5.1.5",
    "dataloader": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "postgraphile": "^4.12.9",
    "postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter": "^2.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. delete node_modules & yarn.lock
2. remove the resolutions
3. run yarn